# Rail render partial in a loop - High Load

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use some like this:

```
render partial: "shared/user/avatar_with_nickname", locals: user
```

I use this partial many times in views of different models and it's conveniently and it's work, but that is bad for time load.

There is console webrick:

> Rendered shared/user/_avatar_with_nickname.html.haml (15.9ms) Rendered
>   shared/user/_avatar_with_nickname.html.haml (14.8ms) Rendered
>   shared/user/_avatar_with_nickname.html.haml (17.6ms) 
>   etc

Is there any way to use it like this and reduce rendiring time? Maybe pre-cache or some else?

Comment: do you preload data?

Comment: do you render your partial each time with different data?

Comment: I get comments like this Comment.includes(:user) and then iterate comments in one view and in every step of iteration render this partial with locals comment.user. So, I can't iterate this partial instead of rendering.

Comment: Thank's to everebody! Tien Nguyen got me thinking about helpers. So, just now I created my own helper and use it instead of partial and ... it's really faster. I see in even in browser load speed (I have a lot comments)

Answer (score 2):

Usually the impact of breaking views to partials is not so big (http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2014/02/13/how-much-time-does-rendering-a-partial-really-take/). So it might be better to optimise other things like helpers and other calculation in partials.

In your situation i can suggest to cache rendered partial according to user. So if you meet multiple comments of one user you will use cached partial, avoiding recalculation of partial.

Something like this should work for you

```
cache "#{user.id}_avatar_with_nickname" do
    # partial content
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution! If it possible don't use rendering in a loop. That is bad idea because of rendering consume time for open/close file every iteration. But sometimes it's necessary or very comfortably to use as in my case.

So, my solution is using helper. I create my own helper *avatar_for* and after this rendering partial became faster a lot.